# how to create procedure/ function in plsql in replacement of static query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I wrote following  static query

```
SELECT (
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATE BETWEEN add_months('22-MAR-17', 0) - 13
                        AND add_months('22-MAR-17', 0) - 7 THEN VOLUME ELSE 0 END ) ) LAST_WEEK_Volume
                    ,(
                        SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN DATE BETWEEN add_months('22-MAR-17', 0) - 6
                                        AND add_months('22-MAR-17', 0)
                                    THEN VOLUME
                                ELSE 0
                                END)
                        ) THIS_WEEK_Volume FROM abc
        )
        )
```

**Problem statemet**- i want to create function for last_Week_volume and this_week_volume and pass it column. can u sugest dynamic query.??
so that through it will be possible to me calculate day wise last week volume and this week volume  for old two year data

Comment: Add sample data and expected results and what you have tried.

Comment: i m new on stackoverflow .could you tell me how to export sample data

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
--creating function

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Calculate_Volume(Date_Val DATE,Start NUMBER, End Number)
   RETURN NUMBER
   IS Sum_Value NUMBER(10,2);

BEGIN
   Sum_Value := 0;

   SELECT (SUM (CASE WHERE DATE BETWEEN add_months(Date_Val ,0)- Start AND add_months(Date_Val ,0)- End then VOLUME ELSE 0 END)) INTO Sum_Value 
   FROM ABC

   RETURN Sum_Value;

END Calculate_Volume;

--Calling the function:

SELECT Calculate_Volume('22-MAR-17', 13, 7) AS LAST_WEEK_Volume, Calculate_Volume('22-MAR-17', 6, 0) AS THIS_WEEK_Volume,
FROM ABC;
```

Comment: Above query  got error :PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "START" when expecting one of the following:
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         current delete exists prior